# Bootstap 5 nav-item padding

Tags: bootstrap-4, nav, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap 4, a padding is automatically applied to the nav-item content. When I'm using Bootstrap 5, the content is stuck to the page border with no spacing. Is this how it's supposed to work in Bootstrap 5 or am I using the wrong class?
example code:

```
<nav class="navbar">
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item">menu<li>
   <li class="nav-item">faq<li>
   <li class="nav-item">contact<li>
 <ul>
<nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing it myself it seems ok for me.
Make sure to use the classes for `<nav>`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
```

The classes have changed a bit, using their provided structure should work fine, it does for me.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/